# Using quantile regression to predict probability of surpassing threshold

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, quantiles, quantile-regression, conditioning

Consider a continuous response $Y$ and design matrix vector $\mathbf{X}$. These are related through some function $f(X) = Y$. Suppose that I am interested in estimating the probability that $Y \leq 0.1$ conditional on observing $\mathbf{X}$.

I want to use quantile regression to do this - **can I confirm that this is a legitimate methodology**?

We have quantiles $\tau \in [0,1]$ and after estimating our quantile regression for each $\tau$ we have our quantile estimates $\mathbf{q} := \{\hat{Q}(\tau) : \tau \in \{0.01,0.02,...,0.99\}\}$. I want to select the $\tau$ such that $\hat{Q}(\tau) \approx 0.1$. When I find such a $\hat{Q}(\tau)$ it seems to then follow naturally that $P(Y \leq 0.1) = \tau$. The reason is that my model has estimated the $\tau$-th quantile to be $0.1$, which is point on the x-axis in $Y$'s pdf that I need to find to be able to determine $P(Y \leq 0.1)$.

In practice this may not work since an estimated quantile can be lower for higher $\tau$ under some $\mathbf{X}$.

Not looking for logistic regression with a discretized response as a solution (since I already know about this).

Comment: A couple of clarifications: 1) Is indexing by $i$ important to the question? 2) You want $P(Y \leq y | X = x)$ but do you know the conditional distribution $P(Y=y|X = x)$?

Comment: Why not use logistic regression?  You have a binary outcome: greater than 0.1 or not.

Comment: @Theja I'm not sure I follow. If I know the latter then I automatically know the former with integration. Also I think the notation is confused -- in the former you use $P$ to mean probability, but in the latter you use it to refer to a density function.

Comment: @zkurtz I had this in an old version -- looking for solutions other than logistic regression.

Comment: OK.  Maybe it would help clarify your problem if you explain why logistic regression is not ideal here.

Comment: @zkurtz I'm fielding alternatives; I will definitely try logistic regression. I just don't want it as the answer because I already know that approach. Just wondering; don't I want to avoid discretizing a continuous response (here, $Y$) and avoid throwing away the information if I can help it?

Comment: @user2763361, I guess the question is whether that information is relevant.  You seem to have asked a binary question: is Y greater than 0.1 or not?  If you had asked "what is the distribution of Y", then reducing to binary would certainly be silly and quantile regression would be obviously advantageous.

Comment: @user2763361, sorry about the abuse of $P()$. I kind of agree with what zkurtz is suggesting. If the only aim is to find P(Y \leq 0.1), then create a dependent variable Y' = 1 if $Y \leq .1$ and 0 otherwise. Then, run logistic regression. From that you can get the probability directly since logistic function's output $\in [0,1]$.

Comment: I've read this question several times, and I can't figure out what you're asking. Looking at some of the other replies I think I'm not alone. You bring up a design matrix, so I assume there's some explanatory variables which it gets multiplied by. But then you say Y is distributed $N(0, \sigma^2)$, with no mention of X - if we know the distribution of Y, why care about X at all? Is Y actually the noise? And what does "...my model has estimated the $\tau$-th quantile to be 0.1, which is point on the x-axis in Y's pdf." mean?

Comment: ...(continued) I think you need to edit your question and add in a section where you define all the variables, explicitly state their relationships, and say exactly what you're trying to find. Give us too much information. I think the answers you get will get better then.

Comment: Can't you create a variable `z := 1 if y >= th else 0` and then use a logistic quantile regression?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that $Y$ is binary.  Ordinal regression is a good choice here.  With any of the ordinal models (proportional odds, proportional hazards, probit, etc.) you can compute the probability that $Y \geq y$ for all $y$.  That probability will change at the unique values of $y$.  The R `rms` package `orm` function implements this efficiently and has a function generator for exceedance probabilities.  If you were extremely fortunate and really have Gaussian residuals you can use the maximum likelihood estimator of the exceedance probabilities, which is a simple function of $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\sigma}$.

Comment: Could you please clarify "it doesn't appear that $Y$ is binary". In the question I said it was continuously normally distributed so this comment is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Someone suggested using binary logistic regression but that would not be the best choice if $Y$ is not binary.